# Maximum of two skewed normal distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, optimization, normal-distribution

Does there exist a means to approximate the maximum of two skewed normal distributions in terms of another skewed normal distribution?

To make it clearer, given 2 skewed normal distributions f(location1, scale1, shape1) and f(location2, scale2, shape2), can we find location3, scale3 and shape3 such that the resultant normal distribution,

f(location3, scale3, shape3) = max{f(location1, scale1, shape1), f(location2, scale2, shape2)}

If there exists an such an algorithm to compute these parameters, can you please point me to it and its complexity? I would like to know for both cases, when the input normal distributions are dependent and when not. Is there a known approach for the beta distributions?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $Y = max({X_1,X_2})$, then:
$$ F_n(y) = P[(X_1\leq y)\cap (X_2 \leq y)]$$

Will that help to formulate your new distribution for Y?

Comment: Thanks. Using the above equation in an exhaustive manner over a finite set of points I can generate a shape of the distribution. However, is there a known distribution for which we can obtain the parameters of the resultant distribution in terms of the parameters of the input distributions? In other words does there exist a distribution that is invariant under the max-plus algebra or if not, atleast approximately invariant such that we can get the approximate output parameters in terms of the input parameters within a certain error?

Comment: I'd suspect that there is no expression for a general case. Maybe some more seasoned mathematicians would like to provide their input? Edit: http://people.orie.cornell.edu/rw339/documents/MasterThesis.pdf this link may contain some more information, maybe in section 2

Comment: Thank you for the link. After reading the thesis, I understand that it is mainly talking about obtaining the maximum of n samples from the same skew-normal distribution. In other words, it studies the extremal properties of "a" skew normal distribution. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: I was looking for work where the maximum of 2 separate skew-normal RVs has been studied. Literature has discussed the maximum of normal RVs and also concluded that the maximum of 2 standard normal RVs can tend to be skewed. They have presented methods to approximate these resultant skew-normal distributions with normal distributions. However, I am unable to find papers that study the maximum of skew-normal RVs. If you are aware of this please point me to the reference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment matching techniques to approximate the maximum of two skew-Normal variables by another skew-Normal distribution. See "[A New Statistical Max Operation for Propagating Skewness
in Statistical Timing Analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.259.3960&rep=rep1&type=pdf)".